# How to fit viewer in python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

I am trying to fit viewer from defining command into frame but I am not sure how to fit it into the frame in the GUI but I am not sure how to increase the fitting into the frame
as below

```
def viewer() :
    supercell = make_supercell(conf, P)
    view(supercell)
    
.
.
.
        self.Frame1 = tk.Frame(self.top)
        self.Frame1.place(relx=0.26, rely=0.09, relheight=0.811, relwidth=0.717)
        self.Frame1.configure(relief='groove')
        self.Frame1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.Frame1.configure(relief="groove")
        self.Frame1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Frame1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Frame1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Frame1.pack(command = viewer())
.
.    
       
def show():
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' , root.destroy)
    global _top1, _w1
    _top1 = root
    _w1 = CreateUserInterface(_top1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you use `place()` then don't use `pack()` because `pack()`, `grid()` and `place()` are three different `Layout Managers` and they can't be use together. If you use `pack()` then it remove setting set with `place()`

Comment: normally to put widget in Frame (or in other widget/window) you should use this frame as first parameter in widget - like `v = Viewer(self.Frame1,...)` and later use `v.pack(fill='both', expand=True)`  to fit `viewer` in `frame`. But I don't know what you use to create viewer.

Comment: don't you get error message when you run code in console/terminal? Standard `.pack()` doesn't have option `command=` - so you should get error.

Comment: Thanks , In the viewer I am using defining function ""def viewer():
     
    conf = bulk('Au')
    P = find_optimal_cell_shape(conf.cell, 495, 'sc')
    supercell = make_supercell(conf, P)
    view(supercell) ""